# Weight gain as a function of calorie intake minus calorie consumption

Tags: weight, calories

If we neglect the effect of dehydration and BM, then is weight gain a one variable function of calorie intake minus calorie consumption? If yes, how many grams one would gain for excessive 1000 calories? If no, what other factors are involved?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: Is it only me, but isn't calorie intake and calorie consumption the same thing? I mean, it sounds confusing. Calorie burn?

Comment: What is "BM" in your question?

Comment: See https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3880593/ for a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I]s weight gain a one variable function of calorie intake minus calorie consumption?

Yes. It stands to reason because why else is the [recommended daily calorie intake](https://www.nhs.uk/chq/pages/1126.aspx?categoryid=51) always talked about in nutritional information labels?  Note, however, that as stipulated in the NHS link,

> These values can vary depending on age, metabolism and levels of physical activity, among other things.

Calories not 'burnt' by the body's metabolism is stored as fat.

> [H]ow many grams one would gain for excessive 1000 calories?

There are no definitive answers to this question as again, it seems to work out differently from person to person due to the components of [intake and expenditure](https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/95/4/989/4576902).

[A link provided by @paparazzo](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/calories-in-a-pound-of-fat) states that with fat working out to be about 3500 calories per pound,

> Some of the studies state that body fat tissue contains only 72% fat. Different types of body fat may also contain varying amounts of fat.
>
> BOTTOM LINE:A pound of body fat may contain anywhere between 3,436 and 3,752 calories, roughly estimated.

### The bottom line on this question

Calories not 'burnt' by the body's metabolism is stored as fat. If you are overweight you need to reduce your calorie intake **and/or** increase your exercise levels.

If you are underweight it is not straight forward as you need to have your weight gain managed.

[There are many possible medical reasons for being underweight](https://www.nhs.uk/chq/Pages/2302.aspx). Speak to your doctor because before trying to put on weight, you need to know that it is safe to do so.

Answer (score -1):

A gram of fat is 9 calories so with a straight up calculation is 111 grams.  [calories in fat](http://healthyeating.sfgate.com/gram-protein-carbohydrates-contains-many-kilocalories-5978.html)  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_energy)

Body fat is not pure fat and is about [3500 calories per pound.](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/calories-in-a-pound-of-fat)  Or about 7.7 calories per grams.  So 1000 calories is about 130 grams of body fat.

Comment: @Chris I provided a link.

Comment: No. 3500 calories = 1 lb of fat is based on bad math and poor extrapolation. It's almost as bad as 220-age = max HR.

Comment: @JohnP You have a tone not becoming of a mod (or regular user).  It is an answer with references.

Comment: There is no tone. It's a simple statement of fact, it's a bad myth perpetuated because it's easy to remember. https://academic.oup.com/ajcn/article/95/4/989/4576902 - Question 3, part C.

Comment: @paparazzo references, yes, but not very scientifically backed...

Comment: @JohnP Question 3, part C is weight loss not weight gain.  Not tone because you declare it is not?  I am not going to debate with you.  You got my feedback.

Comment: It holds true for either weight gain or weight loss. It is repeated because it is simple. Like many things in the body, it isn't simple and it's a bad perpetuation in nutritional science.

Comment: @JohnP Moved on